# TeamSpeak3 server status

Tags: php, teamspeak

I have big problem because, when I'm trying to show status of my ts3 server I have blank page... What am I doing wrong?

```
require_once('libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php');
try
        {
          // connect to server, authenticate and grab info
          $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://query_admin:query_pass@host:10011/?server_port=9987");

          // show server as online
            $serverinfo[$j]['hostname'] = $ts3->virtualserver_name;
            $serverinfo[$j]['online'] = 'online';
            $serverinfo[$j]['players'] = $ts3->virtualserver_clientsonline;
            $serverinfo[$j]['max'] = $ts3->virtualserver_maxclients;

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
          // grab errors and show server as offline
            $serverinfo[$j]['online'] = 'offline';
            $serverinfo[$j]['players'] = '-';
            $serverinfo[$j]['max'] = '-';
        }
```

When I comment this code the page shows as normal...

EDIT:
I see it now, if I only add this 
require_once('libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php');
and nothing more to my code it shows blank page... Is it possible, that library from [here](http://addons.teamspeak.com/directory/addon/integration/TeamSpeak-3-PHP-Framework.html) doesn't work properly?

Comment: Syntax error. Missing a `'` in `require_once(libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php');`

Comment: that's not it, I correcy that, and nothing change...

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you changed the string in `TeamSpeak3::factory`? I guess you've c&p this and expected it to point your own ts3 server automatically...?

Comment: I see it now, if I only add this require_once('libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php'); and nothing more to my code it shows blank page... Is it possible, that library from here doesn't work properly?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But without supplying that code, I'm speculating...

Comment: code of all library I use: http://addons.teamspeak.com/directory/addon/integration/TeamSpeak-3-PHP-Framework.html

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file before the `require_once` and see if any errors come back (if you're not on a production server). Also, I'm assuming you've changed `serverquery://query_admin:query_pass@host:10011/?server_port=9987` to have your host, user, and pass - and that port 9987 is open (`o <host> 9987` (windows) `telnet <host> 9987` (linux) or use [https://www.shodan.io/](https://www.shodan.io/))

Comment: I see the problem is not in the code, the problem starts when I add require_once('libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php'); line to my code. When I add this, it makes blank page and no errors are displayed.

Comment: Make sure the file path is correct. Look at your error logs, `require_once` will report an error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: it is correct, I check it few times...

Comment: Maybe your path isn't correct (even if you say so). Remember that if you have download your API at _yourwebsite.com/libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php_ and the page where you're trying to display it isn't _yourwebsite.com_ then the path should start with a **/**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add echo before each info so the code becomes :

```
require_once('libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php');
try
    {
      // connect to server, authenticate and grab info
      $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://query_admin:query_pass@host:10011/?server_port=9987");

      // show server as online
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['hostname'] = $ts3->virtualserver_name;
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['online'] = 'online';
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['players'] = $ts3->virtualserver_clientsonline;
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['max'] = $ts3->virtualserver_maxclients;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      // grab errors and show server as offline
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['online'] = 'offline';
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['players'] = '-';
        echo $serverinfo[$j]['max'] = '-';
    }
```